# parse xml and put data into bash array

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following xml. I would like to loop through each node and push the `<url>`

value into a bash array if `<extern>` == 1. Any idea how I should approach this?

```
<GraphXML>
      <graph isDirected="true">
        <node name="0">
          <label>font</label>
          <url>http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?</url>
          <data>
            <checktime>0.262211</checktime>
            <extern>1</extern>
          </data>
        </node>
        <node name="1">
          <label>logo</label>
          <url>http://example.com/example.png</url>
          <data>
            <dlsize>7545</dlsize>
            <checktime>0.280600</checktime>
            <extern>0</extern>
          </data>
        </node>
     </graph>
    </GraphXML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using xmllint:

```
out=$(echo "cat /GraphXML/graph/node/url|/GraphXML/graph/node/data/extern" | \
        xmllint --shell input | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g;s/[-][-]*//g;s/\/[^>]*>//')
set $out
i=0
while [ $#  -gt 0 ] ; do
  url=$1
  shift
  extern=$1
  shift
  if [ $extern -eq 1 ]; then
    array[$i]=$url
    let i++
  fi  
done

echo ${array[*]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a ARR
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^\<(url|extern)\>(.*)\</[^\>]*\>$ ]]; then
        if [ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" == "extern" ]; then
            (( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} == 0 )) && unset ARR[${#ARR[@]}-1]
        else
            ARR+=("${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")
        fi
    fi
done < <(grep -oE '<(url|extern)>.*</(url|extern)>' file.xml)

echo "${ARR[@]}"
```

**Explanation**

- `grep -oE` - Uses extended regex `-E` to match either `url` or `extern` and return match `-o`
- `done < <(` - Uses [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to feed `grep` into `while` loop.
- `while read -r line` - Reads a line until `EOF` then `while` exits.
- `^\<(url|extern)\>(.*)\</[^\>]*\>$` - Matches line and saves into `BASH_REMATCH` array.
- `unset ARR[${#ARR[@]}-1]` - Removes last element in array if extern attribute value is 0.
- `ARR+=(...)` - Short form to add new element to array.